# Not able to open HTTPS URL in IOS Simulator with appium and Selenium WebDriver

Tags: ipad, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am using Appium with Selenium WebDriver for automating my web application(having SSL certificate with https in the application url). i am using below code for IPad Simulator.

```
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "iOS");
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "6.1");
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Mac");
            capabilities.setCapability("device", "iPad");
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, true);

            //Create an instance of RemoteWebDriver and connect to the Appium server.
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

But still when i execute my automation script it is not able to open the application url in the IPad simulator.

Can anyone please help me in how to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Appium 1.0+, a number of changes needs to be done with your DesiredCapabilities :

Please match your cap sets with below:

Few Important Points:
Double check the IP & PORT on which Appium server started and mention the same while passing to RemoteWebDriver.

```
 public void setUp() throws Exception
        {
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone Simulator");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1");
            capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "safari");
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),
                    capabilities);

        }
```

Comment: Thank you Abhishek for your response. Actually i am using Appium 0.10.4 version. Do i need to change DesiredCapabilites as you suggested for this version of Appium?

Comment: I don't believe there is any documentation for 0.10.4. You will notice **significant** improvement if you upgrade to 1.1.0

Comment: With the code that i have posted, it was working fine with our web application in Ipad Simualtor when there was no SSL (http in the URL). recently the Web Application URL got changed to https and it stopped working with IPad simulator.

Comment: Okay. I will try to upgrade latest version of Appium i.e. 1.1.0

Comment: If upgrading does not work , please try adding one more capability - 'acceptSslCerts' to true and start Appium server in -no-reset option enabled.

Answer (score 0):

A few corrections to your `DesiredCapabilities`:

- Browser Name should be `Safari`
- Platform Name should be `iOS`
- And shouldn't the URL of your `RemoteWebDriver` be `http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub`?

**[Please review the desired capabilities spec](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#appium-server-capabilities)**

And after you make those corrections, if you try going to `http://www.google.com`, does it work?